# Problems with many to many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables which look like this:

```
[Products table] 1 -> many [Ratings table] many < - 1 [Customers table]
```

Each customer can rate each product once, and I can have 1 product which has been rated by more than one Customer (i.e. many)

My problem is: how can I get the query to list only the products that a specific customer hasn't rated yet?

I tried with:

```
create procedure GetRatings
(
@CustomerID int
)
as
begin
select p.ID,p.Name...
from products p join ratings r 
on p.productID = r.ProductID
where r.CustomerID != @CustomerID
```

But this doesn't kicks out the same products which have been rated by other Customers. So now if I got , lets say, a HP 550 laptop which has been rated twice by different customers,
this query will kick out only the ratings which @CustomerID rated, but not the second one. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: As usual, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: I don't understand , how do you mean ?

Answer (score 3):

All products not rated by @customer:

```
select 
  p.ID,
  p.Name
from 
  products p 
where 
  p.ID not in 
  (select distinct ratings.productID from ratings 
   where ratings.customerID = @CustomerID)
```

All ratings from products that are not rated by @customer:

```
select 
  p.ID,
  p.Name,
  r.*
from 
  products p 
inner join 
  ratings r on p.productID = r.ProductID
where 
  p.ID not in 
  (select distinct ratings.productID from ratings 
   where ratings.customerID = @CustomerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from ratings r
    where r.customerid = ?
      and r.productid = p.productid
)
```

If you want to express this in terms of a join:

```
select p.*
from products p
left join ratings r
    on  r.customerid = ?
    and r.productid = p.productid
where r.productid is null
```